Massive upserts with pg-promise
I've been using the answer from Massive inserts with pg-promise to handle massive inserts of data with much success.
However, I now need to do a massive UPSERT type of operation. Essentially I want to perform a SELECT to get a record if it exists. Then, if it does exist, use some values from it to calculate an updated record and then perform an UPDATE. If it doesn't exist, then it should perform an INSERT to create a new record. I need to do this on a very large number of items, hence wanting to use something similar to the massive-insert functionality.
Is this type of operation even possible?
Thanks.

What have you tried? Postgres has upsert and insert on conflict update.

The logic of UPSERT does not need ColumnSet helpers, as data comes from a query, not memory, so pg-promise way of generating it is not needed for this.

Maybe you just need one single query. Insert or update is standard and using a SELECT to find the data needed, is also standard. Databases are made for handling large amounts of data. "solutions" like pg-promise fix application problems, not database problems.
